# Dúvida com Thread

Tags: delphi, thread, timer

Tenho um formulário onde tenho uma `Thread` para atualizar umas imagens, chamando ela usando um `timer` com intervalo de **19000**, mas está me gerando o seguinte **ERRO** apenas quando é chamada pelo `timer`.

> Project SistemaA.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x00604de7: read of address 0x00000000'.

```
procedure Tfrm01.TimerJogaAutomaticoTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
  //Cria a variavel minhaThread do tipo TMinhaThread
  minhaThread1: TGeraResultadoParaColuna01;
begin
  //Criação do objeto
   ProgressBar1.Position := 0;
   minhaThread1 := TGeraResultadoParaColuna01.Create(False);
   minhaThread1.FreeOnTerminate := true;
end;
```

Comment: Poste também o Execute da Thread para analisarmos...

Comment: @itasouza se consegui ajudar com a minha resposta, pode aceitar a resposta clicando no ✔ no lado esquerdo da mesma. Se necessitar de alguma mais ajuda avise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código básico para criar uma *Thread* é o seguinte, basta substituir o código que escreve no `memo` pelo código para mudar de imagem, tentei detalhar todos os passos o melhor possível:

```
//Declaração da thread 
type
  TThreadSchedule = class(TThread)
  private
    procedure ChangeImage;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

var  //declarar como variável global
  ThreadSchedule: TThreadSchedule;
```

---

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //inicia a Thread
  ThreadSchedule := TThreadSchedule.Create(false);
end;

procedure TThreadSchedule.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  Self.Priority := tpLower;

  //enquanto não terminar a thread faz...
  while (not Self.Terminated) do
    begin
      //chama a procedure ChangeImage; 
      Self.Synchronize(ChangeImage);
      //faz uma pausa de 19 segundos
      Sleep(19000);
    end;
end;

procedure TThreadSchedule.ChangeImage;
begin
  //Escrever aqui o código para mudar a imagem
  form1.memo1.lines.add('Image Changed'); 
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //destroy a Thread para não gerar "MemoryLeaks" por exemplo
  ThreadSchedule.Terminate;
  ThreadSchedule.WaitFor;
  ThreadSchedule.Free;
end;
```

Espero ter ajudado, alguma dúvida avisa.